# Declaring an array of function pointer that takes void as argument and returns an array of pointers to integers

Tags: c

This was asked to me in an interview!

How do I declare an array of function pointers that takes void as an argument and returns an array of pointers to integers?

Can anybody please help?

Comment: That's not a very useful interview question...

Comment: please read this tutorial: http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html. it is really helpfull.

Comment: Trick question? Returning an array is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see... a function pointer `p` that takes `void` as an argument can be declared like so:

```
void (*p)(void);
```

One that returns an array of pointers to integers might look like:

```
 int** (*p)(void);
```

or, following the definition of "array" more strictly (this one is less likely in practice) -- note that as Amir has pointed out, functions in C cannot actually return arrays, but can return a pointer to an array (of 100 int pointers) like so:

```
int* (*(*p)(void))[100];
```

And an array of seven such beasts can be expressed as:

```
int* (*(*ptrs[7])(void))[100];
```

The `void` can of course be dropped, leaving us with:

```
int* (*(*ptrs[7])())[100];
```

This can be confirmed with the excellent [cdecl tool](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int%2a+%28%2a%28%2aptrs%5B7%5D%29%28%29%29%5B100%5D%3B).

Comment: +1 just for the cdecl tool :)

Comment: @Cameron: Can we just use int* instead of int** to return an array of pointers?

Comment: @Ashna: `int*` is a single pointer to an integer. It could be that that integer is the first in a contiguous array of integers (using the pointer to point to the beginning of an array). If the type of elements in the array, however, is not integers but *integer pointers*, then a pointer to the beginning of such an array would be of type `int**` (pointer to the beginning of an array of int pointers). So the short answer is, it depends on what you actually want returned -- an array of integers, or an array of integer pointers :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef int* (*pt2Function)(void * data);
pt2Function funcArr1[10] = {NULL};
```

I don't think that it is possible to return an array, you should create a pionter to it

Comment: That function signature doesn't return an array of pointers, though (nor does it take void).

Comment: @Cameron I think by void argument, it means pointer to void, otherwise it means no argument at all.

Comment: @Cameron I don't think that it is possible to return an array, you should create a pionter to it

Comment: You are quite right about returning arrays, I'll edit my answer.